# iOS Swift Updating Dictionary In An Array

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array of dictionaries inside a dictionary.  I initialize it like this:

```
var fillups:[NSMutableDictionary] = []
```

Then I load it like this:

```
fillups = userDefaults.object(forKey: car) as! NSArray as! [NSMutableDictionary]
```

Then when I try to update a dictionary element in the array I get the "mutating method sent to immutable object" error.  Here's my code to update the record:

```
let dict=fillups[row]
dict.setValue(odometerField.text, forKey: "odometer")
dict.setValue(gallonsField.text, forKey: "gallons")
fillups[row]=dict
```

The error occurs in my first setValue line.

Comment: `as! NSArray as! [NSMutableDictionary]` It's almost as if you *wanted* this to crash some day. ;) Please don't force unwrap and don't force cast. Use optional binding (`if let`) or other safe unwrapping techniques.

Comment: That was actually the syntax that Xcode demanded.  However, I changed it to this fillups = userDefaults.object(forKey: car) as! [NSMutableDictionary] and Xcode liked that.  Still having the same problem, though.

Comment: Then Xcode was misbehaving. It does that sometimes... Force casts are already something to ban as much as possible, so when you see a *double* force cast, you *know* there's something very wrong, and most of the times you have to address the issue yourself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects that you retrieve from `NSUserDefaults` are immutable even if they were mutable when they were inserted.  You need to take the immutable objects you get from defaults and create mutable versions of them.  You also shouldn't force unwrap everywhere if you don't want your app to crash.

```
if let array = userDefaults.object(forKey: car) as? [NSDictionary] {
    fillups = array.map { ($0.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary) }
}
```

You also don't need the `fillips[row] = dict` line since `NSMutableDictionary` is a reference type and editing the reference you pull out of the array is already editing the one inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mutate your dict, you need to declare it with 'var' not with 'let'; 'let' is for constants. Also fix the unwrapping problems pointed out by the comment

```
let dict=fillups[row]
```

should be

```
var dict=fillups[row]
```